# Docker: bind mount file into bind mounted directory creates dummy file

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Consider the following docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    test:
        image: hello-world:latest
        volumes:
          - ./test/foo:/foo
          - ./test/bar.cfg:/foo/bar.cfg
```

Starting this will create a file system within the docker container that is exactly as it should be: there will be all contents of `../test/foo` available in `/foo`, and the `./test/bar.cfg` on as well.

However, it will also create an (presumably empty) `foo.cfg` in the hosts `./test/foo` directory that did not exist there previously.

Being on Windows and ntfs I have a hard time detecting what kind of node that new `foo.cfg` is, it shows up as a file. Might show up as somethihng different (symlink?) on Non-NTFS filesystems, no idea.

My question is: can I set up a docker container with the exact same final file system layout that I have here that does not create that "dummy file"? Copying the files into the image instead of mounting them at runtime is not an option, as I need them to pick up changes while the container is running. It's a development setup and it would be very time consuming to rebuild the containers after every change. As far as I am aware I can also not use docker volumes instead of bind mounts, as that would still need me to stop the service, delete the volume and start it again for changes to become available within docker. Any suggestions?

Comment: Having overlapping mounts, i.e. `/foo` and `/foo/bar.cfg` is asking for trouble

Comment: That I know, But the software I am working on expects the configuration in its main directory, and that is hardcoded. However I do not want to put it in the same directory on my host system, as it should not be a part of what is shared in VCS (I could of course just ignore it there if there is no other way but would prefer not to)